# Get LogLevel for current class/bean

Tags: java, logging, jakarta-ee, apache-commons, java.util.logging

I am using the following approach when logging from my class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;    
...
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
...
log.debug("...");
```

It has come to my attention that all log statements are always executed no matter what loglevel is applied. I do not want to have debug-related statements executed when I do not need it (performance is an issue here).

So I am looking for something like this:

```
if (LogLevel == debug) {
   log.debug("...");
   ...
}
```

How can I obtain the current LogLevel being used for that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each Log instance in the commons logging package can tell you if the specific level is enabled.  Use this code:

```
if ( log.isDebugEnabled() ) 
{
    // Debug log statements
}
```

Check the [Commons Logging JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/logging/commons-logging-1.1.1/apidocs/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Unsure how I could have missed that in the API.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is deprecated, could you refresh it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html) as the logging facade for your logging framework, since it solves the problem you mentioned by using [parametrized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) for improved performance.

If you want an even faster logging framework, use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/).

Comment: I agree, I much prefer parameterized logging over putting in logic checks.